# How do I change a value within a div?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm trying to change the value within a div when I paste in an image in there.

Divs in question:

```
<div class="span4 target">
  <label asp-for="T_Image1"></label>
  <input asp-for="T_Image1" type="hidden" value=""/>
  <span asp-validation-for="T_Image1" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="span4 target">
  <label asp-for="T_Image2"></label>
  <input asp-for="T_Image2" type="hidden" value="" />
  <span asp-validation-for="T_Image2" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="span4 target">
  <label asp-for="T_Image3"></label>
  <input asp-for="T_Image3" type="hidden" value="" />
  <span asp-validation-for="T_Image3" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

A snippet of code which is responsible for changing stuff

```
        return $(".active")
            .css({
                backgroundImage: "url(" + dataURL + ")"
            });
```

Full Javascript/Ajax code (this is a modified STRd6 code)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        var defaults;
        $.event.fix = (function (originalFix) {
            return function (event) {
                event = originalFix.apply(this, arguments);
                if (event.type.indexOf("paste") === 0) {
                    event.clipboardData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
                }
                return event;
            };
        })($.event.fix);
        defaults = {
            callback: $.noop,
            matchType: /image.*/
        };
        return ($.fn.pasteImageReader = function (options) {
            if (typeof options === "function") {
                options = {
                    callback: options
                };
            }
            options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this, element;
                element = this;
                $this = $(this);
                return $this.bind("paste", function (event) {
                    var clipboardData, found;
                    found = false;
                    clipboardData = event.clipboardData;
                    return Array.prototype.forEach.call(clipboardData.types, function (type, i) {
                        var file, reader;
                        if (found) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (
                            type.match(options.matchType) ||
                            clipboardData.items[i].type.match(options.matchType)
                        ) {
                            file = clipboardData.items[i].getAsFile();
                            reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function (evt) {
                                return options.callback.call(element, {
                                    dataURL: evt.target.result,
                                    event: evt,
                                    file: file,
                                    name: file.name
                                });
                            };
                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                            return (found = true);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);

    var dataURL, filename;
    $("html").pasteImageReader(function (results) {
        filename = results.filename, dataURL = results.dataURL;
        $data.text(dataURL);
        $size.val(results.file.size);
        $type.val(results.file.type);
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = dataURL;
        var w = img.width;
        var h = img.height;
        $width.val(w);
        $height.val(h);
        console.log(img.src);
        
        return $(".active")
            .css({
                backgroundImage: "url(" + dataURL + ")"
            });
    });
    var $data, $size, $type, $width, $height;
    $(function () {
        $data = $(".data");
        $size = $(".size");
        $type = $(".type");
        $width = $("#width");
        $height = $("#height");

        $(".target").on("click", function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var bi = $this.css("background-image");
            if (bi != "none") {
                $data.text(bi.substr(4, bi.length - 6));
            }
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $this.addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've tried simply adding .val or .value and other things to the end but that didn't work.

Comment: `div` does not have a value and you can't just paste an image into one. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/IoJbg
It's working based on this.
You see the div <div class="span4 target">?